# Restrictions of /etc/profile in Gnome

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables, gnome3

I have an issue which bugs me for a long time. I'm using the Intel C++ compiler which includes shell scripts to set up environment variables for library paths, include paths and more. *Sourcing* these scripts in `.bashrc` works like a charm for the terminal. Unfortunately, I need the environment variables in *Mathematica* and *NetBeans C++* too, which brings me to the question, how to source the Intel scripts so that they are known by the GUI programs I start.

I searched the net carefully and I think I have tracked the issue down, although I don't have an explanation. One way of setting environment variables for Gnome seems to be to be to create an `*.sh` script in `/etc/profile.d/` which is then executed by `/etc/profile`.

Although, regarding to [this information](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) the `/etc/profile` is not recommended, please note that I have a shell script which needs to be sourced and not only some `export VAR=blub` settings.

If I do this with the e.g. `mklvars.sh` script, it seems that not the complete file is sourced. Let me give a snip from the file to show what I mean

```sh
#! /bin/sh
#
# Copyright (C) 
# ...lot of boring stuff

CPRO_PATH=/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080
export MKLROOT=${CPRO_PATH}/mkl

SCRIPT_NAME=$0
MOD_NAME=mod

# .... some more code here ...

if [ -z "${MKL_TARGET_ARCH}" ] ; then

    echo
    echo "ERROR: architecture is not defined. Accepted values: ia32, intel64, mic"
    mkl_help

    else

    if [ -n "${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" ] ; then OLD_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=":${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"; fi
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${CPRO_PATH}/compiler/lib/${MKL_TARGET_ARCH}: #.....
```

When I now logout/login again, the `MKLROOT` variable is defined but `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was not adjusted. It seems anything which is a bit more complex than a simple `export VAR` is skipped when sourcing the `.profile`.

---

**Question:** Is there a convenient way of sourcing the compiler-variable scripts for an X-Session (in my case Gnome)? Does someone know what goes wrong here?

---

The obvious hack around this issue is to use the final variable definitions after sourcing the scripts manually and put them in the global `profile`. This has the disadvantage that I do this over and over again with every new update of the compiler.

## Step-by-Step

Let me give a step-by-step showcase so that you see that I'm not completely nuts. For this I put the [Math Kernel Library Script](http://pastebin.com/2TdarGAC) on pastebin and I start with the following situation:

- I have not sourced the script in any `bashrc`, `profile` or other file.
- I have logged out and logged in again

For the test we look at the `$MKLROOT` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which both should be changed by the script. Currently, they are not set when I check their values by

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
echo $MKLROOT
```

When I source the file manually, I get:

```
source /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64
echo $MKLROOT
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# Output:
# /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl
# opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/intel64
```

When I put the `source` line into my `~/.bashrc` and open a new terminal, both variables are set correctly as shown above. Now, I remove the `source` line from `~/.bashrc` and put it into `/etc/profile.d/intelCC.sh`, save it and log off/on.

After the login, none of the variables are set, but I have an error message in my `~/.xsession-errors` saying:

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: 1: /etc/profile.d/intelCC.sh: source: not found
```

Now I replace `source` by a simple `.` so that `/etc/profile.d/intelCC.sh` contains now

```
. /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64
```

Same again: Save, log off and log on. Now there seem to be no errors in `.xsession-errors` related to this and finally:

```
echo $MKLROOT
# /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl

echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
# empty
```

Comment: Are you sure your script enters the loop?

Comment: Could you show us the end of the `if/else` block? It looks like the `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not run but since you have not included the rest of the script, I can't tell if it is within an `if/else` block. For example, in the script as shown, if `MKL_TARGET_ARCH` is defined, the `export` will not be run.

Comment: I could post the code, but the [mkl script](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl) is only one example. The Intel compiler comes with many variable scripts and the important thing is: they do work when I put `source /path/compilervars.sh intel64` into my `bashrc` or when I source them manually. Is there an easy way to write some kind of debug message so that I can test which parts of the file are evaluated?

Comment: Not the whole code, just enough to make sure that the loop is being entered. As for debugging, either add an `echo YES > /tmp/foo` or something within the loop so you can be sure it is being run, or add the export line outside the loop to be sure that the loop is not the problem.

Comment: @halirutan - your issue is sounding more and more as if there is a environment setup script that needs to be sourced prior to running the Intel compiler that you're missing in your setup. I would double check with whomever installed this for you (perhaps you) and see if there isn't a file provided by Intel that set's up the path etc. for these scripts so that they can just run.

Comment: @halirutan - if `.` works but `source` doesn't then you might be dealing with Bourne shell and not Bash. Bash supports both whereas Bourne shell (/bin/sh) does not.

Comment: @slm Exactly this seems to be the issue as I have learned a second ago. Ubuntu 12 uses `/bin/dash` as `sh` which seems to be incompatible with the scripts. Thanks.

Comment: @halirutan - also see my additional details to my answer. There is likely a setup script provided by Intel with this product that might help. That file will likely need to be modified if you're on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Confirm MKL_TARGET_ARCH is set

When you add this to the `/etc/profile.d` directory odds are the variable `$MKL_TARGET_ARCH` isn't set or hasn't been set yet, so the entire `if/else` block is essentially skipped.

You can test this theory by temporarily setting the `$MKL_TARGET_ARCH` just above the `if/else` statement and try logging in again to see if it worked.

```
MKL_TARGET_ARCH="..something.."
if [ -z "${MKL_TARGET_ARCH}" ] ; then
```

#### Installing Intel Compilers

I do not possess this compiler so I can't give you exact details but I've dealt with installing engineering applications for the better part of 15 years so I'm somewhat uniquely familiar with the domain.

In any case, when you install these types of tools you typically either have to create your own environment file or one is provided. I found this post regarding Intel's Fortran compiler but I'd be surprised if the products are that dissimilar.

- http://wiki.cecalc.ula.ve/index.php/Installing_Intel_Compilers_on_Fedora

If you look through this post you'll notice a step after installing (`install.sh`), where a file is copied to `/etc/profile.d`. This file contains the environment setup that needs to occur.

```
cp /opt/intel/Compiler/11.1/056/bin/ia32/iccvars_ia32.sh /etc/profile.d/
```

It would be my suspicion that a step similar to this needs to occur for this product as well. Double check your installation was done using distribution specific steps from this page:

- http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-compilers-linux-installation-help

#### Eventual Solution

> if `.` works but `source` doesn't then you might be dealing with Bourne shell and not Bash. Bash supports both whereas Bourne shell (`/bin/sh`) does not.

If you have a look [at this document](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-compilers-for-linux-with-ubuntu) then you see that this seems to be exactly where you problem lies.

> Ubuntu 12.0x changed the link for /bin/sh from /bin/bash to /bin/dash.  Intel installation scripts for 13.0.0.079 reference /bin/sh BUT assume/require this is bourne or bash (sh or bash) but are **NOT** compatible with dash.

Comment: For the C++ compiler it is a bit different. You don't have architecture specific scripts anymore, you specify the architecture as argument to one overall `compilervars.sh` which does the job. Furthermore, I don't want to copy it because if I just call it, I always get the most current version even after an update. Finally, no file is copied during the install to `/etc/profile.d` but you get a message that you have to source the variable scripts appropriately. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @halirutan - you could write a script that does the sourcing of the latest `compilervars.sh` script, and put this script in `/etc/profile.d`, would be another example.

Comment: This is exactly how I do it and it works now like a charm except for one thing: Somewhere after the processing of the profile my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` gets unset. If you can spare a minute and have an idea how to debug this, [I'm in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux).

Comment: @halirutan - I can't chat now, but another suggestion would be to add a `set -x` before commands in these files to enable a more verbose debug message as they're sourced. You typically enable it with `set -x` and disable it with `set +x`.